# Restrict maximum entries for primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, max

I want to have a table where you can have a maximum number of rows (e.g. 3) for the primary key. If there are already three rows for a primary key and another row is added, another one should be removed.

**Example**: I have a table that looks like this:

```
####################################
#   PrimaryKey  |   AnotherValue   #
####################################
|    abcdef     |       123        |
|    abcdef     |       456        |
|    abcdef     |       789        |
|    xyz123     |       sdf        |
|    xyz123     |       5s6        |
|    789klm     |       w8a        |
|    789klm     |       a4d        |
____________________________________
```

I tried to create a `TRIGGER` that only allows a maximum of three entries for each PrimaryKey using the following...

```
 CREATE TRIGGER maxThreeEntries AFTER INSERT ON table
   BEGIN
     DELETE FROM table WHERE (
        SELECT PrimaryKey, COUNT(PrimaryKey)
        FROM table
        GROUP BY PrimaryKey
        HAVING COUNT(PrimaryKey) > 3
     );
   END;
```

... which does not compile.

The inner `SELECT` - when using it alone - works fine for my need and returns the PrimaryKey along with the number of corresponding rows.

Comment: You both didn't put any code which aims at deleting one specific record, as stating the condition of that one record which needs to be removed. But you stated only 1 need to be removed (not all), when a fourth one is trying to be added. So ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER maxThreeEntries AFTER INSERT ON table
       BEGIN
         DELETE FROM table WHERE PrimaryKey IN (
            SELECT PrimaryKey
            FROM table
            GROUP BY PrimaryKey
            HAVING COUNT(PrimaryKey) > 3
         );
       END;
```

you need to compare something in your delete WHERE clause.   You probably also want to add a WHERE clause within the SELECT statement to make sure you are only finding the primary key the trigger looks for.   I am not sure how to do it in mySQL, I mostly work with SQL-Server

Comment: Hi. I get the following response: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table
       BEGIN
         DELETE FROM table WHERE PrimaryKey IN (
            ' at line 1 `.

Answer (score 1):

I have found following solution. There are two triggers. Before insert trigger checks if there are three rows with given primaryKey. If so, then it changes 'primaryKey' of inserted row to some specific value. This row is deleted in after insert trigger.

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER maxThree BEFORE INSERT ON my_table for each row       
    BEGIN
        DECLARE pkc integer;
        SET @pkc := (select count(*) from my_table where primaryKey=new.primaryKey);

        if pkc>2 then
            new.primaryKey:='aaaaaaaaaa';
        end if;       
    END;

CREATE or replace TRIGGER maxThreeAI AFTER INSERT ON my_table 
    BEGIN
        delete from my_table where primaryKey='aaaaaaaaaa';
    END;
```

This solution has one limitation. We are choosing some specific value for primaryKey. I choosed 'aaaaaaaaaa'. But if you will want to insert row with such primaryKey then this row will not be inserted.

What will happen after inserting rows to this table:

```
insert into my_table(primaryKey, anotherValue) values('abc', '111');  -- row inserted
insert into my_table(primaryKey, anotherValue) values('abc', '222');  -- row inserted
insert into my_table(primaryKey, anotherValue) values('abc', '333');  -- row inserted

insert into my_table(primaryKey, anotherValue) values('abc', '444');  
-- this fourth row will not be inserted. 
-- First trigger will change 'primaryKey' value of this row to 'aaaaaaaaaa' 
-- and row ('aaaaaaaaaa', '444')  will be inserted.
-- But then second insert will call 
delete from my_table where primaryKey='aaaaaaaaaa';
-- and this command will delete this fourth row.
```

So after these four inserts only first three rows will be in the table.

I declared variable 'pkc'. Before inserting another row I count rows witch have primaryKey the same as 'primaryKey' of this new row. This count is saved to variable pkc (select into). And then I use this variable in if statement.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your solution. A little thing: I don't want to delete all the rows if the count is bigger than three but rather remove rows until the number of rows for each primary key is equal to three. Any suggestions?

Comment: @StefanSurkamp In my solution not all rows are removed but only this additional one.

Comment: @StefanSurkamp I edited my answer and described how it works.

Comment: Still it's not working properly. I'm sure I have to adapt `pkc number;` to my values... maybe you can clarify what this part stands for?

Comment: @StefanSurkamp I added more explanation to my answer

Comment: I tried to use this code adapted to my table without any results. Is this supposed to work with mysql?

Comment: I wrote my code on Oracle. For MySQL the code is slightly different. See my edit.